# Best way to turn this list bbcode to html?

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

Say have have a bbcode list done like this:

```
[list]
[*]something
[*]something2
[/list]
```

What would be the best way in php to turn that into a html list?

Comment: Maybe [using the BBCode extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) would be worth a try.

Comment: Given that the extension requires server-side installation, you may want to use a pure-PHP library instead.  There are *plenty* of these.  The #1 Google result right now is [NBBC](http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = '[list]
[*]something
[*]something2
[/list]';

$regex = array(
 '/\[list\](.*?)\[\/list\]/is' => '<ul>$1</ul>',
 '/\[\*\](.*?)(\n|\r\n?)/is' => '<li>$1</li>'
);


echo preg_replace(array_keys($regex), array_values($regex), $string);
```

Comment: and what about list inside list?